# Glide 4.7.1 listener not working for onResourceReady method and Exception listener

Tags: java, android, ide, apk, android-glide

there!
I'm using glide to load images in my app. Previously I used Picasso and it worked but after migrating to the Glide (v4.7.1) I'm not able to use listener to get state of the resource. I attached code below please help me in this matter.

```
Glide.with(SlideImageActivity.this)
                    .load(Constant.arrayList.get(position)
                            .getImage())
                    .apply(new RequestOptions()
                            .placeholder(R.color.colorPrimary)
                            .dontAnimate().skipMemoryCache(true))
                    .listener(new RequestListener<String, DrawableResource>() {
                public boolean onException(Exception e, String model, Target<DrawableResource> target, boolean isFirstResource) {
                    spinner.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    return false;
                }

                public boolean onResourceReady(DrawableResource resource, String model, Target<DrawableResource> target, boolean isFromMemoryCache, boolean isFirstResource) {
                    spinner.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    return false;
                }
            })
                    .into((ImageView) imageLayout.findViewById(R.id.image));
```

Error line shows under this

`new RequestListener<String, DrawableResource>()`

If I try to build apk with this then following error shows

> error: wrong number of type arguments; required 1

IDE shows following

> Class anonymous class derived from RequestListener must be declard either abstract or implement methods.

if I implement methods which IDE recommends me, I get following

> error: wrong number of type arguments; required 1

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Try this

```
    Glide.with(this)
            .load("")
            .apply(new RequestOptions()
                    .placeholder(R.color.colorPrimary)
                    .dontAnimate().skipMemoryCache(true))
            .listener(new RequestListener<Drawable>() {
                @Override
                public boolean onLoadFailed(@Nullable GlideException e, Object model, Target<Drawable> target, boolean isFirstResource) {

                    spinner.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    return false;
                }

                @Override
                public boolean onResourceReady(Drawable resource, Object model, Target<Drawable> target, DataSource dataSource, boolean isFirstResource) {
                    spinner.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    return false;
                }
            })
            .into(imageView);
```

Comment: Worked like a charm!!. Thanks mate. So `com.bumptech.glide.load.resource.drawable.GlideDrawable;` is no more in Glide 4.7.1! Please upvote this question.

Comment: I am now upgraded to GlideDrawable to 4.11.0. I can't found drawable in the glide.  com.bumptech.glide.load.resource.drawable.Drawable. What is the import you have used here